# Error : dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, linux

i have a structure defined as

```
50 struct nf_hook_state {
51         unsigned int hook;
52         int thresh;
53         u_int8_t pf;
54         struct net_device *in;
55         struct net_device *out;
56         struct sock *sk;
57         struct net *net;
58         struct list_head *hook_list;
59         int (*okfn)(struct net *, struct sock *, struct sk_buff *);
60
};
```

In my code, i am trying to access it as follows:

```
unsigned int
my_packet_pass_through_hook(void *priv,
                        struct sk_buff *skb,
                        const struct nf_hook_state *state)
{
switch(state->hook){
```

While compiling, it is giving me error :

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘const struct nf_hook_state’ switch(state->hook){
```

Can somebody pls suggest what wrong am i doing here ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to `#include` the header file that contains the `nf_hook_state` `struct`, else the compiler doesn't know the layout of that `struct` when compiling that translation unit.

If it's not in a specific header then it's time to refactor your code accordingly.